# Linq predicate to match objects from many layers of nested collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have:

```
public class TotalPeriod
{
    public ICollection<SubPeriod> SubPeriods { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class SubPeriod
{
    public ICollection<SmallerSubPeriod> SmallerSubPeriods { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class SmallerSubPeriod
{
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Payment
{
    public string PaymentCode { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I need to write a predicate builder that filters the `PaymentCode` which can be found from a list of string.
This is what I have done, but it still returns all results:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TotalPeriod>();
...// other logic
var paymentCodes = new HashSet<string>();
... // other logic to successfully get list of paymentCodes from UI
if(paymentCodes.Any())
{
    predicate = predicate.And(entity => entity.SubPeriods.Any(e => e.SmallerSubPeriods.Any(e => paymentCodes.Contains(e.Payment.PaymentCode))));
}
```

EDIT:

generic predicate builder:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

How the predicate is applied:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<T>> GetManyAsync<T>(Expression<Func<TDAL, bool>> predicate, ICollection<string> includes = null) where T : class
{
    try {
            var expression = Expression.Convert(predicate.Body, typeof(bool));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDAL, bool>>(expression, predicate.Parameters);
            using var dbContext = GetDatabaseContext();
            var entities = await dbContext.Set<TDAL>().Where(lambda).AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();
            ... // other logic
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return DataProviderException.CatchException<T>(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `And()` is not a standard LINQ extension from what I can see. What type is `predicate` and what does `predicate.And(...)` do?

Comment: @Corey I added EDIT to add generic predicate builder, and method `And()` comes from that

Comment: Your `And()` extension looks OK. That leaves the predicate itself. You show how it is composed but not how it is being applied. Somewhere you're going to have to call `Where(...)` to filter the collection. Can you show that code please?

Comment: Do you want just to know if there is any row containing those paymentcodes or do you want to have those objects? If so you need a `Where` clause. And then returning a `bool` in the predicate doesn't make that much sense

Comment: @Link I want to filter object `Payment` where the `PaymentCode` meets the condition

Comment: @Corey I added how the predicate was applied

Comment: Is the generated SQL what you expect it to be?

Comment: There is already handy implementation in LINQKit https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Core/PredicateBuilder.cs
And sample tests
https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/tests/LinqKit.Tests.Net452/PredicateBuilderTests.cs

Comment: Why are you converting the `bool` return from `predicate` to `bool` when it already is? What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL/EF 6.x/EF Core 2.0/EF Core 2.1/EF Core 3.x?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for the link, that definitely helps. I managed to filter in another way outside of this predicate scope. Thanks all.